# Why does my code break while solving Calculate Money in Leetcode Bank problem in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a leetcode daily problem which has following problem statement.

> Hercy wants to save money for his first car. He puts money in the Leetcode bank every day.
>
> He starts by putting in $1 on Monday, the first day. Every day from Tuesday to Sunday, he will put in $1 more than the day before. On every subsequent Monday, he will put in $1 more than the previous Monday.
>
> Given n, return the total amount of money he will have in the Leetcode bank at the end of the nth day.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: n = 4
>
> Output: 10
>
> Explanation: After the 4th day, the total is 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10.

For the following problem my output is coming 6, when i debugged the code, i saw that last value of i=4 doesn't get add to the amount and returns the answer without it.

Below is my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def totalMoney(self, n):
        amount = 0
        i=1

        while i < n:
            amount +=i

            i+=1
        return amount

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n=4
    print(Solution().totalMoney(n))
```

Comment: `while i <= n:` or `while i < n+1:`. But I don't think this is the strategy they're looking for.

Comment: Nope, it's not passing all the test cases.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: `totalMoney = lambda n: int(n/7)*28+(0,1,3,6,10,15,21)[n%7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably an algorithm for solving this that does not involve [too much] iteration but here's an iterative approach FWIW:

```
class Solution:
    def totalMoney(self, n: int) -> int:
        sv = pv = total = 0
        for i in range(n):
            if i % 7 == 0:
                pv = (sv := sv + 1)
            else:
                pv += 1
            total += pv
        return total

print(Solution().totalMoney(20))
```

**Output:**

```
96
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code , i<n will exit when i=4 and n=4,for your logic you can change it to something like this and it will work.

```
class Solution(object):
def totalMoney(self, n):
    amount = 0
    i=1

    while i <= n:
        amount +=i

        i+=1
    return amount
```

But this does not solve the leetcode question.Because you have to change your Monday amount every time with previous monday amount.

This is the solution to the question.I recommend solving it before checking this one.

```
class Solution:
def totalMoney(self, n: int) -> int:
    ans=0
    mondaydeposit=0
    yesterdaydeposit=0
    for i in range(n):
        if i%7==0:
            mondaydeposit+=1
            ans+=mondaydeposit
            yesterdaydeposit=mondaydeposit
        else:
            yesterdaydeposit+=1
            ans+=yesterdaydeposit
    return ans
```

Here I am checking for the day which is my 'i', if i%7==0 then it means i am on monday and i have to increment my previous monday amount. Which will be my previousdeposit for next day, so need to update that too.